# How to move a button with my mouse position in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, wpf-controls

I want to drag(move) a button with mouse position?

**XAML Code**

```
<Button Name="Samplebutton" Content="Moving" Width="100" Height="35"/>
```

In this, i want to move the above button based on the mouse position by any event of button(Normally MouseDown, KeyDown or any one)

Any one please provide suggestion for me?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15354/Dragging-Elements-in-a-Canvas ?? His example accommodates dragging pretty much anything in a `Canvas`

Comment: Got Solution from this site:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/3bbe949b-ca8a-4a6e-a4fb-a8d267e58931